# Django wildcard in request.path

Tags: python, django

don't know much about django but trying to resolve something quickly for a client, they want some content to only show up on certain pages but the code is nav (used across all pages) hence was trying to add:

```
{% if request.path == '/*/projects/' %} something {% endif %}
```

but this doesn't work. Each project has a unique number, hence unique url, but I cannot do:

```
{% if 'projects' in request.path %} something {% endif %}
```

as some pages on the site contain "projects" in the url where we do not want "something" showing. Hence I wanted to use a simple * as wildcard in url, but this does not work.

Many thanks!

Comment: Don't do this in the template, do this in the view. Set a bool flag whenever the template part should be included and use `%if` on that flag.

Comment: Django's template language does not support this kind of non-trivial logic out of the box. But you could write a custom template tag to do it. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: thanks, but beyond my django and programming skills (mostly deal in html and css)...